# Wordpress Website update take time to reflect

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WP website, www.orkunocan.com

If I update the banner, image or menu. It's not showing the updated version on click.

It's taking a day time to reflect the changes, the WP and all plugins are up to date.

Please assist.

It would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web site address is wrong.

Comment: it's about cache, if you use plug-in disable.

Comment: Thanks guys @funkysoulzh reply i solved the issue, as you mentioned its Cache Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any caching plugins in place? Those might be setup wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. U saved my time.